# How to get the id number of a new turtle just created?

Tags: netlogo

I have the following code where I hatch a new agent,

```
to t-of-slowdown [ es-poi ]
  if we-look > 0 [
    set we-look (we-look - 1)
    if (we-look <= 0) [
      if es-poi and (not any? events-here) [
        hatch-events 1 [
          set color green
          set size 5
          set is-poi? true
          set new-poi true
          let m [[ end2 ] of cur-link] of myself
          move-to  m ]
        set events-x ([who] of events-here)
        show events-x
        set we-poi-var va-geometric (1 / 1500) + we-ticks poi
        set sera-poi false 
      ]
      set impregna true
      set color red
      set seguir true
      set we-look random-normal 120 20 ;time to watch an event
      ]
  ]
end
```

which is run in a turtle context (walkers breed) 
A walker is moving by a 'link' (another procedure which calls this one), and when a counter is <0, 
this code generates a new event (events breed) and places it in the same place where the walker is (`cur-link` is the current walker link).
After that, the walker must get the id number of the new event

```
set events-x ([who] of events-here)
```

The problem here is that variable `events-x` get an empty list `[]`. The next time the walker passes by the same event it does get the number-id of the event.

Something must be wrong but I can not guess what it is.
I would appreciate very much if someone could take a look and point me some help.

Regards

Comment: You have `move-to` before you `set events-x ([who ...` - it looks like your new event turtle has already moved to `m` before the walker has a chance to check for any events on its patch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could:

```
let child-who -1
hatch-events 1 [
  ...
  set child-who who
  ...
]
set events-x child-who
```

Or:

```
hatch-events 1 [
  ...
  let child-who who
  ask myself [ set events-x my-who ]
  ...
]
```

Both of these are a bit clunky, sadly. The second one avoids needing to initialize `child-who` to a meaningless value, but it requires using `myself`, a primitive that is likely to mystify the reader.

You could avoid both problems with:

```
let parent self
hatch-events 1 [
  ...
  let child-who who
  ask parent [ set events-x child-who ]
  ...
]
```

(But note that using who numbers at all, for anything, is rarely the best and most idiomatic solution to any problem. It's almost always better to store a reference to the turtle itself.)

Comment: You are right, it is better not use the id of the agent, but I did not know if keys in tables (extension) could be turtles. On the other part, the variable `event-x` is owned by the walker breed agent and not by the event just hatched. Then, could I set `events-x` inside the `hatch-events 1 [ ...  ]` brackets?.

Comment: I've revised my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much indeed. I would like not to use who numbers but I do not know how to use turtles individually as keys in tables. I have been looking for a solution to this like convert the turtle set to a list and use it in a `foreach` construct but I would like to know if there is another approach. I have posted a new question about this matter.